# Is there a distribution that matches my data?

Tags: distributions, sample

I am not an experienced statistician, typically only dealing with normally distributed data. I would like to know if the following data sample can be represented by a well-known distribution?

If so, I assume I can then start to draw/extrapolate assumptions from my data for further analysis, such as what the population of data might look like.

Thanks,
Blake

[image]

Comment: Histograms can be fairly misleading data visualization tools.  Can you label your axes? What about some (any) background?

Comment: 1. Can you tell us something about what the variable is and what it was collected on? Is it likely to be a mixture of heterogeneous subpopulations?  2. It's probably not difficult to come up with a variety of options that wouldn't be a terrible fit (several possibilities occur to me immediately on seeing it), but I think that is usually not a good approach to model selection. What are you trying to pick a distributional model for? (Presumably choosing a distribution is not an end in itself but a step to something else; that something else is likely to be highly relevant to giving good advice.)

Answer (score 7):

This is more difficult to answer than you might hope.

1. There are possibly thousands of **named (or brand-name) distributions** in some literature or another. I doubt that anyone knows about more than a small fraction of them. There is indefinite scope for creating more, given the rather small constraints on what a distribution can be. Although it is a nice if one such looks like a good summary of your data, there is not much real magic in there being a distribution with a name and a more or less straightforward algebraic form for one of more versions of the distribution (density function, cumulative distribution function, quantile function, whatever).
2. (Warning: prejudice ahead) It's also arguable that the most useful distributions are those with **one to three parameters**. Distributions with four or more parameters are often very difficult to fit and even if you can fit them successfully, they aren't necessarily easier or more effective to work with than empirically smoothed versions of the data.
3. Once you allow a distribution to be a **mixture of two or more others** you have even more flexibility, although opinion seems to vary on the usefulness of such exercises. It can make real sense if (and perhaps only if) you know in advance that you have qualitatively different kinds being mixed up, e.g. males and females, and for some reason you can't compare them directly.
4. From the other end, statistical people learn to be a little **suspicious of histograms** unless they have scope to play with bin start and width and get a sense of which features on histograms are genuine and which are artefacts of histogram choices. This is especially true for small samples.
5. It's rare that **subject-matter knowledge** is completely irrelevant as there could be special reasons for bumps and gaps in the data or limits to the data.
6. It is entirely possible that -- even though your distribution may look a bit awkward -- it will look **less awkward on a transformed scale**. As your horizontal axis gives no detail whatsoever on even the sign(s) of your data, specific advice is hard, but by far the most common examples would be logarithmic transformation of a positive variable and square root transformation of a zero or positive variable.
7. You haven't said why you think it's important to name the distribution in terms of a statistical **goal or purpose.** Many statistical methods don't depend at all on knowing the form of any marginal distribution you have, as being normal or gamma or whatever.

That said, in your particular case it appears that you have $\sim10,000$ values, so the small sample worry is ... relatively small.

The detail that catches my eye is a moderately abrupt drop between bin 12 and bin 13. (I would be able to give a less awkward description if the magnitude axis were labelled informatively.) It's my impression that few of the more common named distributions allow that kind of drop.

It's perhaps a useful function of this forum for people with experience of data to assert that very commonly empirical distributions are (much) more awkward than standard forms. Textbooks and courses don't often seem to prepare people for this truth.